# How to display uppercase week day in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS to produce a report where I like to format the date from 20/01/2017 to FRIDAY (uppercase) instead.

```
=UCase(FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_Time.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

What I have tried:

```
=UCase(FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dddd"))
```

However, If I leave the custom field as `=dddd` then it displays Friday.

Question is how to convert to uppercase?!
Your help is much appreciated.

[image: view the screenshot here]

**UPDATE**

The correct syntax would be:

```
=UCase(Format(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dddd"))
```

Thanks to MiguelH & Muhammad Saqlain

Comment: what UCase() return in =UCase(FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dddd"))??

Comment: I tried this `=UCase(FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dddd"))` but does return in actual date + time like when an entry has been made.

Comment: `=UCase(Format(Fields!MyDate.Value,"dddd"))` works for me!

Comment: What result you get? Paste here!!

Comment: i have added a screenshot of what I did ... and the result

Comment: just as an information, the source is a Sharepoint Calendar and the field is `Start_Time.Value`

Comment: UPDATE: works, thanks to MiguelH > I had FormatDateTime and only Format was needed

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be:

```
=UCase(Format(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dddd"))
```

Credit goes to MinguelH